# Apply custom function to specific row/column

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to solve a much larger problem using this basic example.  I need to apply a function based on the location from `which()` because I need to know the year from `df1` where the value is `NA` or >= 150.  Then I subset `df2`, get the mean, and return it to the exact row.  Right now I'm using a `for()` loop and need something much faster as the data I have is very large.  Is there a common way to do this?

dput:

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("USC00031632", "USC00031632", "USC00031632", 
"USC00031632", "USC00031632", "USC00031632", "USC00031632", "USC00031632", 
"USC00031632", "USC00031632"), element = c("TMAX", "TMIN", "TMAX", 
"TMIN", "TMAX", "TMIN", "TMAX", "TMIN", "TMAX", "TMIN"), year = 1900:1909, 
    month = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5), day = c(1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), value = c(30.02, NA, 37.94, 10.94, 
    NA, 28.04, 64.94, 41, 200, 51.08)), .Names = c("id", "element", 
"year", "month", "day", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"data.frame"))

df2 <-structure(list(id = c("USC00031632", "USC00031632", "USC00031632", 
"USC00031632", "USC00031632", "USC00031632", "USC00031632", "USC00031632", 
"USC00031632", "USC00031632"), element = c("TMAX", "TMIN", "TMAX", 
"TMIN", "TMAX", "TMIN", "TMAX", "TMIN", "TMAX", "TMIN"), year = 1900:1909, 
    month = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5), day = c(1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), value = c(30.02, 10.94, 37.94, 10.94, 
    12, 28.04, 64.94, 41, 82.04, 51.08)), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"), .Names = c("id", "element", 
"year", "month", "day", "value"))
```

Code:

```
library(dplyr)

check <- function(df, yr){
  df_d <- filter(df, year == yr)
  m <- mean(df_d$value)
  return(m)
}  

for (i in which(is.na(df1$value) | df1$value >= 150)){
 df1[i,6] <- check(df = df2, yr = as.numeric(df1[i,3]) )
}
```

Comment: I don't really get it as `df1`, and `df2` have identical values, just `df2` is without the `NA`s, can't you just use `df2` and get over with? Or your example data sets are very bad.

Comment: @DavidArenburg The code provides the problem I'm trying to solve.  The data sets are just samples and have no meaning.  It's the programming problem I'm after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend the efficient binary join from `data.table` combined with modification in place (using the `:=`) while specifying `by = .EACHI` (in order to calculate the mean for each group separately).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[setDT(df2), 
           value := ifelse(is.na(value) | value >= 150, mean(i.value), value), 
           on = "year", 
           by = .EACHI]
df1
#              id element year month day value
#  1: USC00031632    TMAX 1900     1   1 30.02
#  2: USC00031632    TMIN 1901     1   1 10.94
#  3: USC00031632    TMAX 1902     2   1 37.94
#  4: USC00031632    TMIN 1903     2   1 10.94
#  5: USC00031632    TMAX 1904     3   1 12.00
#  6: USC00031632    TMIN 1905     3   1 28.04
#  7: USC00031632    TMAX 1906     4   1 64.94
#  8: USC00031632    TMIN 1907     4   1 41.00
#  9: USC00031632    TMAX 1908     5   1 82.04
# 10: USC00031632    TMIN 1909     5   1 51.08
```

---

Alternatively, we could do this in two steps in order to try avoiding the `ifelse` overhead in each step

```
setDT(df1)[setDT(df2), value2 := i.value, on = "year"]
df1[is.na(value) | value >= 150, value := mean(value2), by = year]
df1
#              id element year month day value value2
#  1: USC00031632    TMAX 1900     1   1 30.02  30.02
#  2: USC00031632    TMIN 1901     1   1 10.94  10.94
#  3: USC00031632    TMAX 1902     2   1 37.94  37.94
#  4: USC00031632    TMIN 1903     2   1 10.94  10.94
#  5: USC00031632    TMAX 1904     3   1 12.00  12.00
#  6: USC00031632    TMIN 1905     3   1 28.04  28.04
#  7: USC00031632    TMAX 1906     4   1 64.94  64.94
#  8: USC00031632    TMIN 1907     4   1 41.00  41.00
#  9: USC00031632    TMAX 1908     5   1 82.04  82.04
# 10: USC00031632    TMIN 1909     5   1 51.08  51.08
```

You can get rid of `value2` afterwards if you wish using `df1[, value2 := NULL]`

Comment: Thank you for your code, but I need to apply a more complex function than just mean and I also need more than just knowing the year; also the month, day, and element

Comment: You can apply *any* function within the `ifelse` statement or in the second solution too. If you want to join by more columns, just expend your `on` argument, as in `on = c("year", "month", "day", "whatever")`.

Comment: This does work, but is not exactly what I'm looking for.  I need a way to get the element row to pass to the function I've written in order to do calculations.  This doesn't seem to allow that.  In my problem the `check` function use the row numbers: `check(df = df2, yr = as.numeric(df1[i,3])`

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you need the row number if you already have the value itself? You also can use `which` here. In fact you can use whatever function you like, as you would do in any other case as the two data sets are joined. Other than that, you should really make your question reproducible as no one can't guess what's your real problems is. Finally, you may need to revisit your function and avoid using `which` if you already using the actual numbers.